# @AuthenticationPrincipal how works?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I can't understand how `@AuthenticationPrincipal` works?
As i understand to active this annotation we must add annotation-driven to dispatcher-servlet

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.bind.support.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

But where `@AutheticationPrincipal` get information about the logged user.

```
@RequestMapping
public String getCart(@AuthenticationPrincipal User activeUser) {
    Customer customer = customerService.getCustomerByUsername(activeUser.getUsername());
    int cartId = customer.getCart().getCartId();

    return "redirect:/customer/cart/" + cartId;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/method/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver.html) is responsible for resolving the `Authentication.getPrincipal()` using the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation.

You can see the logic [in the source code of AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/aaa9708b952409269f2829e60126344a1288019e/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/method/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver.java#L116-L121).

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security will register a default filter `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`.

[`SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.html) is uesd for get and set the `SecurityContext` into `SecurityContextHolder`(This has a property  that implements the `SecurityContextHolderStrategy`, it is `ThreadLocal` if you did't set a special mode), it gets the `SecurityContext` from `Session` usually(or after aunthenticated, the context will be set into the `SecurityContextHolder` in other filters), we can get the `SecurityContext` by a static method when in a thread that handle the request by this way :

```
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
```

Finally, after a request finished, `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` will clear `Context`from `SecurityContextHolder`, for example, some threads are reused, that may cause some problems.